Data Source Manager is empty when I run Python application converted to .exe
If we consider that the entire Python application has only this much code: (I'm using: pytwain library for documents canning)
import twain

sm = twain.SourceManager(0)
src = sm.open_source()

When I run the application it works as it should display the Data Source Manager with my virtual scanner. (Also works with real scanners.)
But when I create an .exe file with pyinstaller, it loads the dialog but doesn't find the virtual scanner.
Why does this happen and how can I solve it?
I tried a lot of things. But its not workung. DSM is empty.
But if I run the application with python app.py it's showing sources.

did you run .exe in console to see error message? Maybe it gives some error messages which can explain problem. Code may need some C/C++ llibraries (e.g. files .dll) which it didn't add to .exe. You may have to read PyInstaller  documentation how to add files manually to .exe

if you tried something then you could describe it - it can show what suggestions may not work for you
